# Should a bin directory be full of shell scripts?

Tags: linux, directory-structure

New guy on the team so I figured I'd ask here in public than sound like a complete dweeb and ask elsewhere.  Without giving too much or anything away (please ask questions if you want), but should, or is it in any way traditional, to write code that rolls out a directory containing nothing but script files to /opt/bin?  Shouldn't bin contain... binaries?

I know that most distributions of linux or chock full of scripts in the /bin directory, but was that always the case?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about system administration.

Comment: Your question isn't on-topic for Programers.  I'm not sure if SuperUser would welcome it (I suspect probably not).  [chat] is probably the best place.  Consider dropping into The Whiteboard and asking there.

Comment: @GlenH7 it's actually about code in a package I'm responsible for maintaining. Or to be more specific, code that copies scripts into the /opt/bin folder en masse.  I know it's blurring the lines, but I'm a programmer, not a system administrator... Jim.

Comment: `/usr/bin/firefox` & `/usr/bin/xdg-open` are often a `/bin/sh` script ; and on my Debian I have 408 shell scripts in `/usr/bin/` out of 6880 files there.

Comment: If this isn't on-topic for programmers.se, maybe this is appropriate for the [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange?

Answer (score 7):

Though `*/bin` seems to suggest *by name* that the contents therein are BINaries, the *BSD* `hier` man-page does *not* seem to suggest it. It only seems to suggest that the contents be executable. In particular:

```
 /bin/         user utilities fundamental to both single-user and multi-user environ-
               ments

 /usr/         contains the majority of user utilities and applications

               bin/      common utilities, programming tools, and applications
```

I've seen linux man pages that use similar language, explicitly calling out the *executable* nature of `*/bin` folders. Here are a few `hier` man pages:

- linux [hier (7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/hier)
- freebsd [hier (7)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?hier(7))
- Mac OSX [hier (7)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/hier.7.html)

<sup>(The `(7)` in the man pages is indicating section 7 which is "Overviews of various topics, conventions and protocols, character set standards, and miscellaneous other things." separating it from a hypothetical hier library call, command, game, or configuration)</sup>

Comment: now if only I could spell heir not that way...

Comment: not to forget /usr/local/bin ;) for user specific binaries/scripts